# How to sum a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, variables, sum

```
list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["5", "6", "7", "8"], ["9", "10", "11", "12"]
```

How do I make `list1 = ["10"], ["26"], ["42"]`?

Also, how to assign a variable to `10` or `26` or `42` afterwards?

(I am using Python 3.)

Comment: Please read a basic tutorial before posting such questions.

Comment: correct you input, it should be a list of lists

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> list1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["5", "6", "7", "8"], ["9", "10", "11", "12"]
>>> 
>>> [str(sum(map(int,i))) for i in list1]
['10', '26', '42']
>>>
```

You can always unpack the list.

```
>>> a,b, c = [str(sum(map(int,i))) for i in list1]
>>> a
'10'
```